# Unable to resolve JRE: mustang (Standard VM)

Tags: java

I am working on a project using Eclipse(IDE) where i am getting this error

*Unable to resolve JRE: mustang (Standard VM)*

I saw this in project>>properties>>Libraries (Tab).

am using jdk1.6.0_18. is any buddy knew about this error ?

please help me out.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be `JRE 6(Mustang)` is not available on specified path. Check JRE in

```
Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

1. From Eclipse menu select Run > Run configurations... >
2. Select the configuration you want to execute (like JUnit, Maven
   Build etc) from LHS pane.
3. On the RHS pane look out for JRE tab.
4. Now select appropriate Runtime JRE (like Workspace Default JRE)